# Embed Python in Python?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, introspection

I wrote a "compiler" [PypTeX](https://github.com/sloisel/pyptex) that converts an input file `a.tex` containing `Hello @{3+4}` to an ouput file `a.pyptex` containing `Hello 7`. I evaluate arbitrary Python fragments like `@{3+4}` using something like `eval(compile('3+4','a.tex',mode='eval'),myglobals)`, where `myglobals` is some (initially empty) dict. This creates a thin illusion of an embedded interpreter for running code in `a.tex`, however the call stack when running `'3+4'` looks pretty weird, because it backs up all the way into the PypTeX interpreter, instead of topping out at the user code `'3+4'` in `a.tex`.

Is there a way of doing something like `eval` but chopping off the top of the call stack?

## Motivation: debugging

Imagine an exception is raised by the Python fragment deep inside numpy, and pdb is launched. The user types `up` until they reach the scope of their user code and then they type `list`. The way I've done it, this displays the `a.tex` file, which is the right context to be showing to the user and is the reason why I've done it this way. However, if the user types `up` again, the user ends up in the bowels of the PypTeX compiler.

An analogy would be if the `g++` compiler had an error deep in a template, displayed a template "call stack" in its error message, but that template call stack backed all the way out into the bowels of the actual g++ call stack and exposed internal g++ details that would only serve to confuse the user.

## Embedding Python in Python

Maybe the problem is that the illusion of the "embedded interpreter" created by `eval` is slightly too thin. `eval` allows to specify globals, but it inherits whatever call stack the caller has, so if one could somehow supply `eval` with a truncated call stack, that would resolve my problem. Alternatively, if `pdb` could be told "you shall go no further up" past a certain stack frame, that would help too. For example, if I could chop off a part of the stack in the traceback object and then pass it to `pdb.post_mortem()`.

Or if one could do `from sys import Interpreter; foo = Interpreter(); foo.eval(...)`, meaning that `foo` is a clean embedded interpreter with a distinct call stack, global variables, etc..., that would also be good.

Is there a way of doing this?

## A rejected alternative

One way that is not good is to extract all Python fragments from `a.tex` by regular expression, dump them into a temporary file `a.py` and then run them by invoking a fresh new Python interpreter at the command line. This causes `pdb` to eventually top out into `a.py`. I've tried this and it's a very bad user experience. `a.py` should be an implementation detail; it is automatically generated and will look very unfamiliar to the user. It is hard for the user to figure out what bits of `a.py` came from what bits of `a.tex`. For large documents, I found this to be much too hard to use. See also [pythontex](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Comment: This isn't really an answer (which is why it's a comment) but have you looked at the possibility of using a `pdb` instance created with the [`skip` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb) which lets you list modules which the debugger won't step into?

Comment: Thanks for this, I had not noticed the `skip` parameter and you are right, it might slightly improve the illusion of an embedding. Separately, I have now taken note of [jinja2.debug](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/9b4b20aa56fde3a5cd5ac49d4feacd96eacb832d/jinja2/debug.py), which is possibly also related.

Comment: Hm, according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects), objects of the builtin traceback type can now be constructed and mutated to some extent. That might be all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a sufficient solution:

```
import pdb, traceback

def exec_and_catch(cmd,globals):
  try:
    exec(cmd,globals)            # execute a user program
  except Exception as e:
    tb = e.__traceback__.tb_next # if user program raises an exception, remove the
    f = e.with_traceback(tb)     # top stack frame and return the exception.
    return f
  return None                    # otherwise, return None signifying success.

foo = exec_and_catch("import module_that_does_not_exist",{})
if foo is not None:
    traceback.print_exception(value=foo, tb=foo.__traceback__, etype=type(foo))
    pdb.post_mortem(foo.__traceback__)
```